# Picasso - Hide ImageView If Any Error Occurs While Loading The Image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-imageview, picasso

Trying To Figure It Out From Around 5 Hours, But Still Not Found Helpful Way.

**The Code I'm Using Is :**

```
Picasso.with(context).load.(url).into(imageView);
```

But I Want To Set ImageView Visibility To Gone If Image Doesn't Loads.

**Something Like This :**

```
Picasso.with(context).load.(url).error(imageView.setVisibilty(View.GONE).into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 11):

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(imageView, new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
                            
    }

    @Override
    public void onError() {
        imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```